# Batch- Load variables from separate file?

Tags: variables, batch-file, cmd, save, loading

How do you load variables from a separate file in Batch? For example, if I wanted to type:

```
set bbat=False
```

Into a .txt file and then save it. How would I load it into my Batch program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rename you file as .BAT an then call it:

```
@echo off
echo set bbat=False>test.bat
call test.bat
echo %bbat%
pause
```

If you really need it as .TXT file :

```
@echo off
echo set bbat=False>test.txt
for /f "delims=" %%a in (test.txt) do %%a
echo %bbat%
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just wanna save and load it try this: `@echo set bbat=false >save.cmd`
to load the variable try this: `call save.bat`
then to see the variable type: `echo %bbat%`

Comment: that's not only the very same solution than in the accepted answer (more than 5 years ago) - except yours inserts a (possibly fatal) trailing space.